# Website printing out code

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, pdo

The website: [Website](http://multiplayersurvival.net/)

You can see the problem i'm having on the website above, i have no idea why this happens.
I've got PDO, PhP, httpd, php-mysql and so on and it still doesn't work.

I've tried reinstalling the whole thing.
I've followed countless tutorials on how to fix the usual "printing out code" problems.

It's not php, cause i can to phpinfo();
phpinfo can be found on [this](http://multiplayersurvival.net/info.php) webpage.

Mysql is working, cause that caused a different error that doesn't show up now.
Is there anything else i might've forgotten?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `short_open_tag` is `Off` turn it on.

Your code is written using short tags `<? ?>` and due to this Off parameter,

it expects to be `<?php ?>`

To do it, go to your `php.ini` and change `short_open_tag` to `On`

Comment: Really?!? And here i was looking for some complicated problem! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Your server does not have [short tags enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). You either need to enable it or change your short opening tags (`<?`) to full opening tags (`<?php`)